# Spring , HIbernate need assistance

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

This is my `index.jsp`

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="text-center">Rupasinghe Trust Invesments</h1>
            <div
                class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-2">
                <div class="myForm">
                    <form:form class="form_signin" method="POST" commandName="user" action="login">

                        <%-- <form:input path="branch" type="text" class="form-control" name="branch"
                            placeholder="Branch Code" required="autofocus" /><br />
                         --%>
                             <form:input path="username"
                            type="text" class="form-control" name="username"
                            placeholder="Username" required="autofocus" /><br />

                             <form:input path="password"
                            type="password" class="form-control" name="password"
                            placeholder="Password" required="autofocus" /><br />

                        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn"/>
                    </form:form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my `LoginController.java`

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@ModelAttribute("user") User user , BindingResult result){

        return "mainFrameAdminPanlel";
    }

}
```

This is the bean `User.java`

```
@Entity
public class User {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userId;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="branchId")
    private BranchEntity branch;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<UserAccess> userAccess;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public BranchEntity getBranch() {
        return branch;
    }

    public void setBranch(BranchEntity branch) {
        this.branch = branch;
    }

    public Set<UserAccess> getUserAccess() {
        return userAccess;
    }

    public void setUserAccess(Set<UserAccess> userAccess) {
        this.userAccess = userAccess;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

}
```

I am getting this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
```

I am new to spring and still couldn't get what is wrong with this. Please help ! Thank you in advance

Comment: Try removing `BindingResult` from `login()`

Answer (score 0):

When you load the first page itself, I mean the page containing the form, you need to pass an instance of User. This exception is thrown since you have not passed instance of User that you are trying to use in the form. Kindly check.